# Unable to run VMware Player 3.0.0-203739 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, vmware

As the title states I am unable to run VMware player 3.0.203739 on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system, when attempt to run the program I get the following error message :

"Kernel Headers 3.2.0-23-generic-pae

Kernel headers for version 3.2.0-23-generic-pae were not found. If you installed them in a non-default path you can specify the path below. Otherwise refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions and click refresh to search again in default locations."

However while installing the the program I install the essential headers required using the following commands :

sudo apt-get update and
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic

Any suggestions as to way this happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`linux-headers-generic` is a meta package which usually installs the appropriate headers, but it looks like something went wrong here.

Please install the headers manually with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

---

#### Please use VMWare player *4.0.x*!

Comment: Using the command that you gave me it I get a list of linux headers . I explicitly installed installed linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae, however I still seem to get the same problem. Should I install the entire list of headers?

Comment: @Staffinator: you need to be using the latest vmware player. I don't think 3.x.x supports the 3.2 series kernel...

Comment: I can't run the Vmware Player 4.x.x. series because it seems to be for 64-bit hardware only, is there any way to run older Vmware players on Ubuntu?